# EPL Online Tool from Esper Tech gives a status 0

Tags: esper

I am testing the [Esper EPL Online Tool](http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html) with the default example written on the form. However, when I click the "Submit" button, I only get a pop up with the message "Status 0".

Should the example run as it is or am I missing something? Is there a problem with the online tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to ask the support of that tool.

Comment: I did. However, I immediately received an email pointing out that I should
open an issue in StackOverflow or Github.

Comment: I tested it just now and had no status 0. Maybe attach a screenshot. Try empty forms to see if that is also a message. Are you trying to access this from a special device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems it had something to do with the firewall set by the university network. I tried accessing it from the outside and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.